# Bad Image Format exception in Asp.Net Core web application(.NET Framework)

Tags: asp.net

I have ran into an issue while using a VC++ project reference in my asp.NET Core web application solution(.net Framework).

1. Created a new asp.NET Core web application.
2. Added a VC++ project (CLR-->Class Library)
3. Added a C# Class Library project and added VC++ project reference in the References of C# Class Library.
4. Call the method in C# Class Library in the Main Project which in turn return a value from VC++ Class Library

The solution builds with out any error, but at run time I get the error

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'CppClassLibrary, Version=1.0.6164.19946, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I have set my build Platform as AnyCPU for the main Project and C# Library Project, and for VC++ Class library it is Win32 which are all by default.

My machine is Windows 7 64 bit.

We cannot get rid of VC++ references as it would be high impact change in our existing application suite.